# Laravel base_path() undefined in loaded class

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I've autoloaded a helper class using composer.json through:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
     ...
    ],
    "files": ["app/library/test.class.php"]
```

However when using (any) laravel package along, base_path() and other helper functions are undefined. 
Are they being loaded before vendors ? or what is the issue here?

I want to use Laravel helper functions in this class.

Comment: I have a helper file setup like this and it works. `"files": ["app/helpers.php"]`. Also, don't forget to do `composer dump-autoload --optimize`. Can you be specific in the errors please?

Comment: the error is that the functions are undefined, issue happens when any package from vendor try to use any functions in the helpers

Comment: Any file is automatically added via `include` during autoloading if it is mentioned as `"files"`. If it doesn't work, then you are using namespaces and messed them up a bit. Show us more code of the code using that function, and the code defining the function.